# ASP.NET webapi or SignalR?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am working on a Cordova app. I would like to know if I can continue with ASP.NET webapi at the server side or can I use SignalR.

Which one is better and why. What are the pros and cons. Please provide as much information as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One uses web sockets, the other does not. It really depends on your needs, but you could always use both if you wanted to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read the [tour] and [ask]. Questions like this aren't welcome. You can perfectly do comparisons between two products yourself using a notepad and a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) is for real-time bi-directional communication. [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) uses request/response that is initiated by the client.

So there is no "better" one as they serve different purposes.

Comment: @thanks i watched the tutorial by microsoft